# Kendo grid custom editor dropdown list doesn't reflect the selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I create a `dropdownlist` as an `editor` on a `grid`, it works, but when I click on the dropdownlist and select an item then click somewhere else (lose the focus of dropdownlist), the selected item doesn't reflect to the grid, I see the text before the selection (but actually it is selected, when I click on the same item I see the item in the dropdownlist that I've selected)

Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/uMws5/2/

How do I make the selection reflect to the grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I commonly solve this problem in the Kendo grid is to create lookups of the available selection items which I can then use to retrieve the value to be displayed in the grid by its id:

```
 window.lookups = {};

 var userTypeLookup = window.lookups["user_type"] = {};
 $.each(user_type, function (idx, value) {
     userTypeLookup[value.typeid] = value.typename;
 });
```

In the column template I can reference the lookup to get the display value:

```
{
      field: "typeid",
      editor: userTypeList,
      template: '#= lookups["user_type"][typeid] #'
}
```

Here is an updated Fiddle which implements this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/uMws5/4/

Comment: I thought that there is a solution already included in KendoUI and I'm missing something, as I'm new to KendoUI and JQuery.
I'll wait for a while before to accept your answer as there may be other ways more suitable. I have many grids and dropdownlists on them, so this method is not really useful for me, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: I'm surprised that if this is a know problem. By the way how their own example works as expected, http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html I see no difference except transport/update/create.

Comment: The Kendo example is working because the selected value is bound to an object that contains both the id and the name. Like you, I wanted to use only the id, since the example approach wasn't going to work with my data model. To help with creating lookups across multiple different grids and lists, I have settled on a naming convention in my application to provide "id" and "displayname" properties for these items when they're serialized to JSON.